# 'Suspected' Odd behavior from output of Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping

Good Day, I am running the following snippet and find the following behavior which I am not sure if it is correct or not:

```
for url in links:
        driver.get(url)
        date = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[contains(@id, 'node')]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span""")
        secref1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[3]/div/section/div[2]/div/section/div/section/div/article/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div""")
        secref2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[3]/div/section/div[2]/div/section/div/section/div/article/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div""")

        if not secref2:
            secref2.append("Null")
        else:
            secref2 = secref2

        num_page_items = len(date)

        for i in range(num_page_items):
            print secref2

driver.close()
```

I expect "secref2" to be missing from the webpage, hence the IF/ELSE.

my output is as follows when running the script:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64592/devtools/browser/da7ab0e6-e0e9-4edb-963a-913b38c6f4dd
['Null']
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a7bc63bef087357d1510c3b28ec8db87", element="0.14518628426304736-4")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a7bc63bef087357d1510c3b28ec8db87", element="0.6063690703515521-4")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a7bc63bef087357d1510c3b28ec8db87", element="0.16122194044687665-7")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a7bc63bef087357d1510c3b28ec8db87", element="0.7547639796767653-4")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a7bc63bef087357d1510c3b28ec8db87", element="0.768240568661338-16")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a7bc63bef087357d1510c3b28ec8db87", element="0.3077014556092601-4")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a7bc63bef087357d1510c3b28ec8db87", element="0.9689075758046188-4")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a7bc63bef087357d1510c3b28ec8db87", element="0.09545508090332766-4")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a7bc63bef087357d1510c3b28ec8db87", element="0.068763767350847-4")>]
```

I see the first "Null" however subsequent entries look to be some sort of output.

If I try:

```
        for i in range(num_page_items):
        print secref2[i].text
```

I get the following error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64788/devtools/browser/df696310-30cf-4833-89fa-fac28e6b3bb0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 54, in <module>
    print secref2[i].text
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating twice. So in the first URL, you get Null. In subsequent URLs you get a list of webelements. You can't print `secref2[i].text` because the first time you hit it, it is "Null" and "Null" is a `str`.

Did you mean to assign something else to the variable here? I don't know why you'd assign the variable to itself.

```
else:
    secref2 = secref2
```

Comment: thanks Lucas - not sure if was correct, but my reasoning was the following. If secref2 is not available, make the variable "Null" otherwise make the variable whatever selenium was able to get. would you suggest "pass" ?

Comment: something I didn't add to this is the fact that driver.get(url), sequentially opens 10 URL's and extracts the pieces of information from the Xpath's I specify. On on of the 10 URL's I expect "secref2" to not be available. hence I want "Null" as the value in that instance

Comment: But it IS doing that. You're assigning `secref2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath` which will give you a list of webelements or an empty list. `secref2 = secref` has no effect. Your output shows that it's working as you intend, on the first URL it gives you an empty list, so you add "Null", on the next 9 URLs it finds one webelement and prints the list containing that one element. If you want the text from the webelement found, use `secref2 = secref2[0].text`

Comment: I moved the if/else to the portion the script where I will be writing to CSV. this is what I have: 
`with open('results.csv', 'a') as f:
            for i in range(num_page_items):
                    if not secref2:
                        secref2.append("Null")
                    else:
                        secref2 = secref2[i].text
                    f.write(date[i].text + "#" + secref1[i].text + "#" + secref2[i].text +"\n")
`

however I get the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text' which is correct - however how do I get around it ?

Comment: as stated above, when secref2[i] is "Null", it is a string. so doing secref2[i].text is basically saying take that object (a str) and apply .text . But there is no such attribute for a str. So at some point, some combination of your date[i], secref2[i], or secref1[i] is a str and you're trying to apply the .text attribute to it

so do something like `if type(secref1[i]) != str:  secref1[i] = secref1[i].text` etc.   

then you could do your `else: secref2 = secref2[i] f.write(date[i] + "#" + secref1[i] + "#" + secref2[i] +"\n")` and drop the `.text` since you made sure they're all strings